# lenovo bluetooth keyboard does not recognize FNLK in ubuntu =(

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

everything works fine, except that in my ubuntu OS it is still impossible to use FnLk so I have to use Fn if I want to press F1-F12. In the Windows it works OK. Anyway the keyboard is good and I hope someone from Ubuntu community will suggest some workaround soon.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, following this guide solved the issues:

https://github.com/lentinj/tp-compact-keyboard

The link provides a udev script that will fix your problem, run it with 
`sudo ./tp-compact-keyboard --fn-lock-enable`

Comment: Late to the game, but it works perfectly! Thanks!