# Bluetooth keyboard prints wrong symbols, and doesn't recognize -, p, [, 0 (thinkpad compact bluetooth keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, keyboard-layout, xinput

I connect (using [console](http://devasive.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-persistent-bluetooth-pairing.html) approach, gui doesn't work) "ThinkPad Compact Bluetooth Keyboard" (US layout) to thinkpad t420.

Trackpoint on this external keyboard and most of the buttons work well, except <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd> not recognized at all, and pressing <kbd>/</kbd> outputs a sequence smth like "bn/". Sometimes, if press <kbd>p</kbd> and some other symbols,  then <kbd>p</kbd> is also printed.

Here is the output of `xinput -list` (notice that there is no second keyboard, but there is a new slave pointer -- it is marked with ** below):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ **ThinkPad Compact Bluetooth Keyboard with TrackPoint id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]**
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So far:

- tried changing layout (via keyboard layout settings), but no luck.
- tried `showkey --scancodes` on that problematic symbols: returns nothing!

If we cannot get even scancodes -- does it mean no chance to get them working? 
(i mean no "easy" way, writing a driver is not considered.)

**Any ideas?**

(running Ubuntu 12.04)

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/362303/41363) question is related (about need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> to make work <kbd>f1</kbd>-<kbd>f12</kbd>), but also not answered.

Comment: If you google some more you will find out that without a linux driver it won't work. e.g. [link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=294577). Maybe write to Lenovo, and send them this [link](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Will-there-be-a-Linux-driver-for-Thinkpad-Bluetooth-Compact/td-p/1241049) from their own forum. But I doubt they would do anything.

Comment: Or file a bug against the Bluez [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bugs).

Comment: @falconer thanks for the link! it inspired to try `schowkey`. Although your link doesn't have my problem of not recognizing the symbols 'p','0', etc.

Comment: Hmm. Did you try this keyboard on other computers? And if `showkey --scancodes` returns nothing please also look in the `/var/log/syslog` file whether it reports unkown keys, like *"atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x55 on isa0060/serio0)"*

Comment: @falconer 1) haven't tried, but will try, looks suspicious, 2) No such messages or others 'suspicious' mentioning 'key' or 'pressed' or 'unknown' in any of /var/log/*.log files

Comment: Then it is clear, that the kernel doesn't get any keypress events from those buttons. And based on the fact that the other problem reports about this keyboard doesn't report similar problems to yours (*As you pointed it out*), I think the only conclusion is that this is a defective keyboard. If you don't have another BT appliance near, you may try `hcidump`, (as the guy did in my first link), whether anything is sent from that keyboard when you press those keys.

Comment: @falconer seems you are right - the keyboard is just defective: 1) tried with android -- the same issue 2) hcidump on pressing '0' shows nothing! If you add an answer with smth like "based on comments we deduced that the keyboard is defective" i will accept it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments with [Ayrat](https://askubuntu.com/users/41363/ayrat) we deduced that the particular keyboard is defective.